# GetRequestStream() freezes if there is no internet connection

Tags: c#, mono, webrequest

I've managed to spawn an asynchronous web request and setup a timeout for it. However, the setup of the connection is still on the UI thread and it seems to freeze on `GetRequestStream` if there is no internet connection. How to solve this?

```
private WebRequest getPostLoginRequest (string username, string password)
{
    string postData = string.Format (@"<login><user>{0}</user><password>{1}</password></login>", username, password);
    byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);

    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create (String.Format (@"{0}/auth/", baseServiceUrl));
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/xml";
    request.ContentLength = buf.Length;
    request.GetRequestStream ().Write (buf, 0, buf.Length);

    return request;
}
```

Comment: That would be such a perfect fit for the async framework... Well, you will have to create a different thread, of course, and work with callbacks :)

Comment: So what's the use of BeginGetResponse and EndGetResponse if you still have to create a new thread to start them in. And where do I setup the timeout for GetRequestStream?

Comment: well, use `BeginGetRequestStream` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()` creates the network connection to the remote server, so it can block - use `BeginGetRequestStream()` instead.

The implementation of `GetRequestStream ()` is actually just a thin wrapper around `BeginGetRequestStream ()` / `EndGetRequestStream()`: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs#L816

There's nothing that could possibly block in `WebRequest.Create()`, so it's safe to call this from the UI thread.